# Javascript Moment Time add Time Calculation wrong

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using *Moment* library in **Javascript**

I would like to add time, so I tried:

```
var time1 = moment("10:00:00", "HH:mm:ss");
var time2 = moment("00:03:15", "HH:mm:ss");
var add = time1.add(time2);
let format = moment.utc(add).format("HH:mm:ss")
console.log(format);
```

I will expected my `format` will be `10:03:15` but turns out it gave me `18:03:15`
I wonder why it add another 8 hours for me, well considered as `.utc` problem, I try to perform without `.utc` as follows:

```
let format = moment(add).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

It return `02:03:15`.

It kinda frustrated I dunno what is happening

*By the way

```
var add1 = time3.add(5588280, 'ms');
```

*it works fine by adding with `h, m, s, ms` to it

Comment: I guess you shouldn't try adding two datetimes. Rather use `.add(3, 'm').add(15, 's')` on the datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, with moment `add` you could add time in 3 ways:

```
moment().add(Number, String);
moment().add(Duration);
moment().add(Object);
```

This is the version `moment().add(Number, String);`

```js
var time1 = moment("10:00:00", "HH:mm:ss");
var time2 = moment("00:03:15", "HH:mm:ss");
var add = moment(time1).add(time2.minutes(), "minutes").add(time2.seconds(), "seconds");
let format = add.format("HH:mm:ss");
console.log(format); // without utc
let formatUtc = moment.utc(add).format("HH:mm:ss");
console.log(formatUtc); // with utc
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This is the version `moment().add(Object);`

```js
var time1 = moment("10:00:00", "HH:mm:ss");
var time2 = moment("00:03:15", "HH:mm:ss");
var add = moment(time1).add({minutes: time2.minutes()}).add({seconds: time2.seconds()});
let format = add.format("HH:mm:ss");
console.log(format); // without utc
let formatUtc = moment.utc(add).format("HH:mm:ss");
console.log(formatUtc); // with utc
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You already know the third version :)

Comment: wow that was a details explanation for me, great help :D

Comment: @Lawraoke no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

`add` is the two-argument function with the need first argument as the number and second argument is number type in time laps.

i.e it is working with microseconds

```
time3.add(5588280, 'ms')
```

Here you can do for your problem

```
const time1 = moment("10:00:00", "HH:mm:ss");
const time2 = moment("00:03:15", "HH:mm:ss");
         // get hours from time2 and add in time1
const add = time1.add(time2.format('mm'), 'hours')
        // add minutes using chain 
       .add(time2.format('mm'), 'minutes')
        // add seconds using add method from moment 
       .add(time2.format('ss'), 'seconds');

const format = moment(add).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

By using UTC on the moment it converts time into UTC and format make it as
time string format

```
moment(add).format("HH:mm:ss")
// Your required time:- 13:03:15
moment.utc(add).format("HH:mm:ss")
// required time in UTC:- 07:33:15
```

Comment: so that means I had to split up while adding two time at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can **simply** use [moment duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) function to `add` two times together we do **not** use to use extra lines code *(like minutes, seconds, or hours)* here to get the `results` you want.

Just `add` two times with `duration` and get them as `milliseconds` and then `format` them as you like to.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let time1 = "10:00:00"; //string
let time2 = "00:03:15"; //string
let addTwoTimes = moment.duration(time1).add(moment.duration(time2)) //add two times
let format = moment.utc(addTwoTimes.as('milliseconds')).format("HH:mm:ss") //format
console.log(format); //10:03:15
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: let me try out and get back to you :)

Comment: @Lawraoke No worries. This should just work fine for you. Let me know if i can help further.